# Xamarin.UITest, System Drawing Reference Error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest

I came into this when I tried to install Xamarin.UITest as NuGet package in an Android project.
When I try to compile the project I have that error:

> Can not resolve reference: System.Drawing, referenced by Xamarin.UITest. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for System.Drawing, or remove the reference to Xamarin.UITest.  MyApp.Android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Xamarin.UITest` NuGet package does not belong in the Android project.

It must be in its own project which is typically a .NET Framework project.

Here's a sample Xamarin.Forms app that includes a UITest project that you can use for reference: https://github.com/brminnick/UITestSampleApp